# How can I determine the RGB values to use to match a native Apple Watch complication?

Tags: ios, colors, uicolor, watchos

I'm building an Apple Watch complication with a gauge. I want to match the color of the gauge to one of the system complications (the built-in Battery complication).

I took a screenshot on my Apple Watch, transferred it to my Mac, and used the built-in macOS app Digital Color Meter with the dropdown set to *Display native values*. Depending on where I hovered the PNG screenshot, I got anywhere from `100, 216, 124` to `101, 217, 124`. This surprised me, because I would have expected the whole gauge to have the same values, since a complication only accepts one UIColor as the `tintColor`. These were the same whether I had True Tone and Night Shift turned on or off on my Mac.

I used, for example, one set of the values I got to create a UIColor for the complication's `tintColor` like this:

```
let complicationGreenColor = UIColor(red: 100/255,
                                     green: 217/255,
                                     blue: 124/255,
                                     alpha: 1)
```

When I used this set of values and then run the complication on my Apple Watch, I can see that the colors vary slightly from the system complication. It's hard to perceive, but the colors are different. And, when I take a screenshot of my complication, transfer it to my Mac, and check it with Digital Color Meter, I get completely different RGB values than what I used when I created the UIColor, and they don't match the system complication that's in the same screenshot. In this example, I got `131, 212, 133`, which was different than the expected `100, 217, 124`.

I've also tried using Digital Color Meter on the system Battery complication in the watchOS Simulator, and got `101, 217, 125`.

One of these sets may be the "correct" values, but with so many different possibilities, **how can can I reliably determine the correct RGB values to use to match the system complication color?**